# webpart context.session is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, null, httpcontext

I've been using the session array to store a state variable for my webpart... so I have a property like this:

```
    public INode RootNode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Context.Session["RootNode"] as INode;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Context.Session["RootNode"] = value as object;
        }
    }
```

This usually works fine.  I've discovered that sometimes, the context.session variable will be null.

I'd like to know what are the conditions that cause the session to be null in the first place, and whats the best way to persist my object when this happens? Can I just assign a new HttpSessionState object to the context, or does that screw things up?

---

Edit:  Ok, so its not just the session that is null... the whole context is screwed up.  When the webpart enters the init, the context is fine... but when it reaches the dropbox selectedindexchange postback event (the dropbox contains node id's to use to set the rootnode variable), the context contains mostly null properties.

also, it only seems to happen when certain id's are selected.  This looks more like some kind of weird bug on my end than a problem with my understanding of the session.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

However, the context doesn't depend on the class, per say.  It depends on the context of the page/handler that is using.

-Theo

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what type of file this is in but I had a similar problem with an .ashx file.  The solution was that the handler has to implement IReadOnlySessionState (for read-only access) or IRequiresSessionState  (for read-write access). eg:

```
public class login : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState { ... }
```

These Interfaces do not need any additional code but act as markers for the framework.

Hope that this helps.

Jonathan